# what are drone.io 0.8.5 plugin/gcr secretes' acceptable values?

Tags: drone.io

I'm having trouble pushing to gcr with the following

```
gcr:
    image: plugins/gcr
    registry: us.gcr.io
    repo:  dev-221608/api
    tags:
      - ${DRONE_BRANCH}
      - ${DRONE_COMMIT_SHA}
      - ${DRONE_BUILD_NUMBER}
    dockerfile: src/main/docker/Dockerfile
    secrets: [GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS]
    when:
      branch: [prod]
```

...Where GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS will work, but if named say GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_DEV it will not be properly picked up.  GCR_JSON_KEY works fine.  I recall reading legacy documentation that spelled out the acceptable variable names, of which GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS and GCR_JSON_KEY were listed among other variants but as of version 1 they've done some updates omitting that info.

So, question is, is the plugin capable of accepting whatever variable name or is it expecting specific variable names and if so what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drone GCR plugin accepts the credentials in a secret named `PLUGIN_JSON_KEY`, `GCR_JSON_KEY`, `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS`, or `TOKEN` (see code [here](https://github.com/drone-plugins/drone-docker/blob/c02aa47d64997938d01633e4ef012b677ac4614b/cmd/drone-gcr/main.go#L18-L22))

If you stored the credentials in drone as `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_DEV` then you can rename it in the .drone.yml file like this:

```
    ...

    secrets:
      - source: GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_DEV
        target: GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS

    ...
```

Comment: thanks, just what I was looking for and the additional tip will go a long way!